# ORACLE : insert row if not exists - duplicate key error

Tags: sql, oracle, composite-primary-key

There was a bunch of similar questions, but I need to write my code.

I know that, as a good practice, I should use `seq.nextval` instead of `SELECT NVL(Max(...`, but my homework is to write procedure, not create new sequence.

I need insert new row if `NAZWA` is not duplicated, but have to increment `ID`.

Table `MIEJSCOWOSC` has two columns (**PK** `ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI` as NUMBER, `NAZWA` as VARCHAR2)

It is clear for me that my sequence counter
    `SELECT NVL(Max(m.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI)+1,1) INTO mID` 
is not working properly as I receive:

> An UPDATE or INSERT statement attempted to insert a duplicate key.

How should I repair this code?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WstawMiejscowosc (
    NM IN Miejscowosc.Nazwa%TYPE) 
AS
    mID Miejscowosc.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI%TYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT NVL(Max(m.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI)+1,1) INTO mID
  FROM Miejscowosc m;
  INSERT INTO Miejscowosc m
    select mID, NM
    from Miejscowosc 
    where not exists (select 1 from Miejscowosc m where m.Nazwa = NM);
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't do what you think it does.

Your insert statement selects *all the rows* which don't match the input parameter `NM`.  So when you have more than one non-matching row in the table your statement will attempt to insert that many rows of `NM` with the same derived value for `id`.  This is why you get the `ORA-00001` exception.

Solution: check for the existence of the passed value, and insert just one record if that value is not found.  .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WstawMiejscowosc (
    NM IN Miejscowosc.Nazwa%TYPE) 
AS
    mID Miejscowosc.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI%TYPE;
    x varchar2(1);
    cursor c_nm_exists (p_nm varchar2) is
        select null into x
        from Miejscowosc m
        WHERE m.Nazwa = NM;

BEGIN
    open c_nm_exists(p_nm);
    fetch c_nm_exists into x;
    if c_nm_exists%notfound then
            select Max(m.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI)+1,1)
            into mID;
            INSERT INTO Miejscowosc m
            values (mID, NM);
    end if;
    close c_nm_exists;
END;
/
```

This is a clunky piece of code.  However, it is better than my previous suggestion because it avoids the use of exception to implement business logic and it handles the passed NM value matching more than one row.  It still has multiple selects on the table but the various constraints make this inevitable.

---

I always worry about showing students how to do do their homework by implementing bad practice.  Why can't teachers set their students exercises which require them to implement good practice?

A solution with a putative index might look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WstawMiejscowosc (
    NM IN Miejscowosc.Nazwa%TYPE) 
AS
    mID Miejscowosc.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI%TYPE;
    x varchar2(1);
    cursor c_nm_exists (p_nm varchar2) is
        select null into x
        from Miejscowosc m
        WHERE m.Nazwa = NM;

BEGIN
    open c_nm_exists(p_nm);
    fetch c_nm_exists into x;
    if c_nm_exists%notfound then
            INSERT INTO Miejscowosc m
            values (m_id_sequence.nextval, NM);
    end if;
    close c_nm_exists;
END;
/
```

Although that could be simplified to a MERGE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE WstawMiejscowosc (
    NM IN Miejscowosc.Nazwa%TYPE) 
AS
begin
     merge into Miejscowosc m
     using (select NM from dual ) q
     on (q.NM = m.Nazwa)
     when not matched then
          insert values (m_id_sequence.nextval, NM);
end;
```

This is a better solution because:

1. using a sequence is more scalable than selecting `Max(m.ID_MIEJSCOWOSCI)+1,1)`
2. using a single statement works better in a multi-user environment

Checking for the non-existence of a value in a table is always problematic.  If two sessions check for the same `NM` simultaneously neither will find it (because of Oracle's read commit isolation level): consequently both will insert records for the same value.  The only safe way to prevent this scenario is to put a UNIQUE constraint on the column in question.  (This also scales better than locking the whole table in exclusive mode.)

Comment: Thanks. Looks I need to figure out the IF statement to not insert row when it exists

Comment: This code is still wrong - think a while what can happen in multiuser environment, when two processes try to insert a record at the same time.This still will end with `duplicate key error` from time to time.

Comment: @mallorn - okay I have revised my question to provide a better solution in the first case and to provide solutions using a sequence.

Comment: @kordirko - my point regarding bad practice in homework questions was intended to cover scalability and data integrity.  However, I have expanded my answer to cover those issues.